# Protractor : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when resolving a promise

Tags: protractor

I'm new to Protractor and writing some sample test cases.So while trying to get the text of an element, I'm not able to resolve my custom promise.When i try to print it says **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined** .  Here's is what i'm trying to do.

```
let temp = "u";
var another = function (para) {
var obj, size = 0;
let version;
var promise;
let text_1;
element.all(by.xpath('//td[@class="ellipsis"]/span[@class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope"]'))
    .each(function (element, index) {
        element.getText()
            .then(function (text) {
                size++;
                version = element.all(by.xpath("//td/span[@class='ng-binding']"));
                text_1 = text;
                if (para == text_1) {
                    version.get(size - 1).getText().then(function (temp) {

                        console.log("done->" + temp);
                        //promise= Promise.resolve(temp);
                        promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(version.get(size - 1).getText()));
                        console.log(promise);
                    });
                };
            });
    });
return promise;
};



describe('testing', function () {
it('testing', function () {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8090/xxxxxxxx');
    var para = "aa  ";
    protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(function () {
        another(para).then(function (t) {
            console.log("success->" + t)
        });
    });
});
});
```

The output is as follows:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you init the `var promise` in nested `then` of `element.all().each()`, which is executed async. When `another(para)` execute complete, its return value `promise` still undefined. Next execute `Undefined.then()`, that's why you get error:  Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Change below code lines in function `another` as following:

```
// return element.all().then() as the function return value

return element.all(by.xpath('//td[@class="ellipsis"]/span[@class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope"]'))
    .each(function (element, index) {
        element.getText()
            .then(function (text) {
                size++;
                version = element.all(by.xpath("//td/span[@class='ng-binding']"));
                text_1 = text;
                if (para == text_1) {
                    version.get(size - 1).getText().then(function (temp) {

                        console.log("done->" + temp);
                        //promise= Promise.resolve(temp);
                        promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(version.get(size - 1).getText()));
                        console.log(promise);
                    });
                };
            });
    })
    .then(function(){
       return promise; // return the promise in element.all().then()
    });
```

Comment: Thanks yong. Worked perfectly.